# MySQLConnector throws NullReferenceException when calling Open() in Mono

Tags: c#, mysql, mono, mysql-connector

I've got a little project that connects to an MySQL Database. In Windows 7 it works like a charm, but when I do exactly the same in Mono (with monodevelop and a test mysql server locally) I get a `NullReferenceException`. I have looked in the connector mannual and in the known bugs, but I don't have a clue.

Maybe someone out there knows why this occurs:

[image]

[**Click here for larger picture**](http://i50.tinypic.com/2eajhmu.png) 
(a screenshot from monodevelop with error details)

```
    private static IDbConnection connection;
    private static IDbCommand command;
    private static IDataReader reader;

    public static void Init()
    {
        try
        {
            string myConnectionString = "SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;" +
                            "Database=game;" +
                            "UID=root;" +
                            "PASSWORD=root; Pooling=false";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            connection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error at creating connection: " +e.Message);
        }

    }

    public static void LoadMaps()
    {
            connection.Open();

            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM maps";

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string Name = reader.GetString(1);
                int width = reader.GetInt32(2);
                int height = reader.GetInt32(3);
                Console.WriteLine(ID + " " + Name);


            }
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
            command.Dispose();
            command = null;
            connection.Close();
    }
```

EDIT: its hard to believe, but sometimes it works, i really don't know why, esspecially because I have changed nothing. strange...

Comment: FWIW, I really find it hard to believe that it's anything that you're doing wrong. I suspect there's a bug with the MySQL Connector. I've been googling for `get_ConnectionString NullReferenceException MysqlConnection` with little luck.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem?  We can't see your code.  This is likely a code issue on your end, which means, your never sucessfully making the connection.

Comment: i have updated my post with the code i use. Init is called right befor LoadMaps.
Thanks for your great support.

Comment: @Markus Have you opened a bug with the MySql Connector dev team yet? I'm pretty sure that should be your next step. Before you do, make sure that you're running the latest version, and that the bug is still reproducible.

Comment: @Lynn: I wanted, but the problem dissappeard without any trace. I have changed nothing. I will open a a bug when this problem occurs the second time. But for now, i cant reproduce it....strange

Answer (score 0):

Well that code is way too late in the piece isn't it?
the object connection is null, so you go need to look at where it's being created.

Comment: I disagree; the debugger shows it instanciated and populated with properties. The stack trace shows the NullReferenceException way down in a compare method being called by get_ConnectionString()

Comment: you are right, the connection isnt null. its created in a method that is called before that one seen on the screenshot

Comment: Hard to see in the image of the stack, but it seems to be passing in a name = value pair, which I'd initially assume was in the connection string, and trying to compare the key name with something, so is it right?